# problem with my hard disk

Tags: windows, mac, filesystems, ntfs

My Toshiba external hard drive is not being detected on Windows PCs, but works flawlessly on my Mac.

File system is NTFS.

Comment: we need more details...

Comment: I bet you must have plugged it first into your Mac? And Mac suggested to format it to its like? And you just did so?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a USB disk you could start by downloading a USB utility like "usbdeview" to see whether the USB controller is recognising a device connected. If not, check your cabling.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to ensure that your USB hard drive is being detected by the windows OS.

Open Device manager

- Start menu --> Right click "Computer --> Click Properties --> Select "Device manager"

View by device connection

- View | Devices by connection
- ACPI-x64 based PC | Microsoft ACPI Compliant system | PCI Bus

You should be able to see multiple PCI-to-USB bridges

Search under that and see if you see the "USB Mass Storage Device"

For example, I see:

```
+ PCI Bus
   + ...
   + Intel (R) ICH9 Family USB2 Enhanced Host Controller - 293A
      + USB Root Hub
          + USB Mass Storage Device
              + Seagate FreeAgent Go USB Device
```

If you see it correctly, then the USB device is detected.

Then what you need to do is to see whether the filesystem is correctly detected.

Open Computer Management.

- Control Panel | Administrative Tool | Computer Management
- Storage management | Disk management

You should be able to see it mounted.

Tell us where you can't follow and let us help you =)